# FragmentActivity within Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I need help because I implemented a navigation drawer , but I need this load a FragmentActivity

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment objFragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
        case 2:
           // objFragment = new menu3_Fragment();
            break;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

I need to load the MainActivity in a fragment.

Comment: Have you tried `getActivity()` ?

Comment: I need load the Fragment Activity in th fragment. If i start the activity with the startActivity works , but what I want is to keep the navigationdrawer

Comment: You need to either convert your activities to fragments and embed them or clone the ui to those activities

Comment: I have other activities to fragments , the question is that the Main handling other fragments .

Comment: I understand I have to have a single fragment , in this case the navigation drawer i then load the fragments in this

Comment: I solved, i implented public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks{